Flutter expand from icon to search bar but without suggestions area
Flutter documentation describes two useful material3 widgets SearchBar (which provides a full-row search bar, that is like a text input) and SearchAnchor (which provides a search view and suggestions area; can be used both with SearchBar and standalone - for example, a simple icon, when clicked - opens the search view).
I am trying to achieve the latter behavior but with a twist: I want a search icon (for context, I want to put this icon to the app bar); when clicked - it expands to a standard search bar (but not full screen, showSearch() is not viable ) and it must not have suggestions area. Is this possible using these widgets?
Something like this:
Before click - only icons is visible
After click - searchbar expanded, no suggestions
My workaround right now is just providing viewConstraints for SearchAnchor with no enough space for suggestions area - but this is very bad (see the second screenshot for how it looks - divider line is still visible).
return SearchAnchor(
        viewConstraints:
            BoxConstraints(minWidth: 550.0, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 58),
        isFullScreen: false,
        searchController: _controller,
        viewHintText: "hint",
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
          return IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              controller.openView();
            },
          );
        },
        viewOnSubmitted: (text) {
          _controller.closeView(text);
        },
        suggestionsBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
          return List<ListTile>.empty();
        });

Any help is appreciated.

Could't that be achieved with a Hero animation too and your custom SearchBarWidget?

I think yes, but I was wondering If I can achieve this behavior with just these 2 widgets provided by flutter, before I will implement custom solutions. Maybe I was just missing something

Did you find a solution for this ? I'm trying to do the same. I tried to chang the viewConstraints like you but I always got a overflow error even with a height of 100. By the way how could you achieve this behaviour with a hero element ? don't the Hero element need two similar widgets to make a transition effect ? how could you transition between a icon button to a textfield ? Sorry for all those questions. Thanks in advanced
